# UITextAlignment in swift

Tags: ios, swift

How to Align `UItextView` programmatically ?
I don't need the

`label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;`

But I want to choose the alignment exactly.

Comment: What do you mean 'choose the alignment exactly'?

Comment: The exactly coordinate, in this case the "x".

Comment: Why not change the position of the `UITextView`?

Comment: what do you mean with "then" ?

Comment: I think the best way is to programmatically change the x of the whole text view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTextContainerInset:
```

Is what you are looking for I believe.